# How can I retrieve the machine code from a ARM stm32f4?

Tags: assembly, arm, disassembly

I want to retrieve the code uploaded to a ARM (stm32f4). 
My particular problems are related to a program uploaded to [Pixhawk](https://pixhawk.org/choice).

I just want to backup the program that is already on the ARM board. I know that I cannot get the code back, I just want to retrieve the image to, if I want, program it again with exactly the same image (firmware).

Are there tools that help with this? Preferably for a linux system.

Comment: Try [this](http://www.micromouseonline.com/2009/05/08/stm32-arm-cortex-bootloader/#axzz1cSz9mzrr).